# Create an abstract method without fixing the types of its parameters

Tags: java, parameters, typing

I'm trying to implement a Class structure, where I'm able to create Box-Objects of different types. These types are: `Squares, Circles, Rectangles and Hexagons`.

For the abstract father `class Box` I'd like to specify a `setDimensions()` method that has to be implemented in all child objects.

However, the dimension parameters for all objects are different (Except for the height):

`Circles` have a `diameter`, `Rectangles` have a `width and length`, and `Hexagons` and `Squares` have `equally sized sides`.

Is it possible to define a Interface/abstract method that can handle this type of job?

//EDIT: This is for a programming assignment. Obviously all classes have suitable constructors, but this program "simulates" a project where the implementation of a design pattern is supposed to be useful. I'm trying to apply the `prototype` pattern, where you clone a basic box and set the parameters based on another box that I would like to place in the new one. 
I know it isn't a terribly good example, but we have to solve it that way. Alternatively a `factory pattern` is also an option, but I would like to avoid having to write too many factory classes.

Comment: I don't understand the last part you added. "clone a basic box and set parameters based on another box". Why don't you just clone the other box to begin with? :)

Comment: Basically the idea was to give each box a .pack() method that creates a new box from the prototype (Which is supposed to simulate a problem where creating a new object would be very processing intensive) and to set the dimensions based on the box that is to be packaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my two cents.

You could have something like this in abstract superclass

```
public abstract void setDimensions(double... dim);
```

And one sample implementation (rectangle) would be

```
// expected params are width and height
public void setDimension(double... dim) {
    if (dim.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Two dimensions expected, width ang height!");
    }
    ...
}
```

And you would call it like this

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
rec.setDimensions(1.5, 2.8);
// rec.setDimensions(1.0); would throw IllegalArgumentException
```

Restrictions are that you would have to know what parameters you would have to supply, and if you are wrong you will get `IllegalArgumentException` in runtime, instead of compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, I was totally unaware of this syntax! I'll give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: It's a shorthand for `double[] dim`, saves you from instantiating an array when you call the method. Hopefully I didn't put any syntax errors in the code, I wrote it here directly.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I wasn't aware I would just pass an Array that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small implementation for the classes:

```
  interface Dimension{
       int getWidth();
       int getLenght();
       int getRadius();
      }

    CircleDimension implements Dimension{
       int radius;
       int getWidth(){
            return -1;
       }
       int getLenght(){
            return -1;
       }
       int getRadius(){
          return radius
       }
   }
    RectangleDimension implements Dimension{
       int width;
       int length;
       int getWidth(){
            return width;
       }
       int getLenght(){
            return length;
       }
       int getRadius(){
          return -1;
       }

class Box{
  void setDimension(Dimension dimension);
}
```

And in the subclasses of the Box class, you can do:

```
class Rectangle{
    int length;
    int width;
    setDimension(Dimension dimension){
      if(!dimension.getClass().equals(RectangleDimension)){
             //thow illegal argument exception
      }else{
       length = dimension.getlength();
       width  = dimension.getwidth();
      }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a parallel class hierarchy for dimensions ...

```
abstract class Dimensions {}
class Radius extends { double r; }
class WidthHeight extends { double w; double h; }
```

Then you can have your `setDimensions` method just take `Dimensions` as argument.

I am not sure I see a utility of this though: since the notion of "dimension" is vastly different between your concrete classes, there seems to be no use for the superclass method. It sounds like it belongs to the child classes: `Circle.setRadius(double r);`, `Rectangle.setWidth(double w)`, `Rectangle.setHeight(double h)` etc.

`Square` (or `Diamond`?) could extend Rectangle, and override the two methods by calling the other as well to make sure that the sides remain equal.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **Dima** and **dasblinkenlight** that it doesn't look like `setDimensions` belongs to `Box`. However - as an alternative answer to the question - there's also a way to achieve this using generics:

```
abstract public class Box<D> {
    public abstract void setDimensions(D dimensions);
}

class Square extends Box<Double> {
    public void setDimensions(Double dimensions) {/*-*/}
}

class Circle extends Box<Double> {
    public void setDimensions(Double dimensions) {/*-*/}
}

// (say Tuple is a generic container for two elements)
public class Rectangle extends Box<Tuple<Double, Double>> {
    public void setDimensions(Tuple<Double, Double> dimensions) {/*-*/}
}
```

**Edit**: The benefit of using generics is that you can specialize the type of the argument of `setDimensions`. Note that, if you define a class hierachy with an abstract class `Dimension` on top, you cannot override `setDimensions(Dimension dimensions)` with a **covariant** argument type, that is, you cannot override it as, e.g., `setDimensions(CircleDimension dimensions)`.